# How to give Perspective access without Cube access?

Tags: xmla, iccube

in a Cube, I have a calculated measure `[Nb>4]` depending on a measure `[Nb]`, filtering only the values above 4.

We don't want users to see the underlying measure `[Nb]`, so I defined a perspective which hides it using `-[Measures].[Nb]`

I am looking for a way to give access to a perspective without giving access to the cube it depends on... (because using xmla (Excel), users can currently see the perspective **and** the cube).

I tried to do that using the roles definition module, but it seems not to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the 'default' perspective (see first [image](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/adv_perspectives.php)). This perspective is a special one that applies visibility to all cube.

It should be possible then to hide your measure

```
  -[Measures].[Nb]
```